# Taking a subset of a dataframe according to an integer vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and it has four columns. Now I want to take a subset of this dataframe according to an integer vector. I tried to use subset and looked at other posts in vain.

```
b=c('p','q','r','s','t','u')
a=c('at','bt','ct','dt','et','ft')
d=c(22,23,24,25,26,27)
e=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
dat=data.frame(b,a,d,e)
dat
  b  a d  e
1 p at 22 1
2 q bt 23 2
3 r ct 24 3
4 s dt 25 4
5 t et 26 5
6 u ft 27 6
test=c(2,5)
```

Now I want to select all the rows (keeping all the columns too) that are in test that is 2nd and 5th rows and keep all other columns.

Comment: Please provide sample data. Also, look at the documentation for `%in%`

Comment: @jihoward, I have reframed the question. I can select directly the rows but the original dataframe is large.

Answer (score 1):

Given your definitions of `dat` and `test`,

```
dat[test,]
#   b  a  d e
# 2 q bt 23 2
# 5 t et 26 5
```

or

```
dat[dat$e %in% test,]
#   b  a  d e
# 2 q bt 23 2
# 5 t et 26 5
```

The first approach just treats the elements of `test` as row numbers of `dat`. The second extracts all rows of `dat` for which `dat$e` is in `test`.